# AJAX caused IIS dead?

Tags: jquery, ajax, linq, linq-to-sql, iis

I use ajax (jQuery) dynamic load another 7 to 8 pages into my home page, similar to igoogle, when refresh several times or more people visit, the following issues came out:

HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected Internet Information Services

then IIS dead, can not access. I suspect that is because AJAX asynchronous request to create too many connections, leading to IIS can not handle.

Configuration:

XP
IIS 5
NET 4

Access the database using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly.  Are you just asking if the multiple simultaneous requests could have been the cause of the bug?  Absolutely.

Comment: yes, Mike. it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that details the limit:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/10/10/31476.aspx

Defaults to 10 connections, can be configured upwards to a max of 40.

Comment: This error code is almost Windows clients only. Never happen on Windows servers, unless you hit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248074/EN-US

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are developing locally, you should not be hosting any website on Win XP IIS instance.

IIS on Windows XP is not the same as IIS on Windows Server, you will continue to have problems.

Regardless of what you do, you will continue to have problems until you use the appropriate platform, there are many excellent (and free) choices available to you these days.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off **keep alives** on your web site.

IIS 5 has a limit on number of requests it can process at the same time. Production websites should be hosted on Server version of Windows, not XP.

Comment: i changed the connection timeout to 5 seconds, but the error still open, i will turn off Keep Alives and check. tks